# Worst performance if using OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I'm trying to parallelize my code using OpenMP, basically attacking every for loop that i see it's worth parallelizing. But i can't manage to get better performance in any implementation. Here's a simple example:

```
double start = omp_get_wtime();

            #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
            for(int y=0;y<hl;y++) 
                for(int x=0;x<wl;x++) 
                {
                    dI_l[x + y*wl][0] = 0.25f * (dI_lm[2*x   + 2*y*wlm1][0] +
                                                dI_lm[2*x+1 + 2*y*wlm1][0] +
                                                dI_lm[2*x   + 2*y*wlm1+wlm1][0] +
                                                dI_lm[2*x+1 + 2*y*wlm1+wlm1][0]);
                }

            double end = omp_get_wtime();
            std::cout << "   wall time : " << end - start << std::endl;
```

The time without the pragma varies but it's around: 0.000385959. When i add the pragma goes to: 0.00149408.

I've tried adding 'schedule' clause with different number of chunks and many other implementations but i never seem to get better performance.

hl is 240 and wl is 340. dI_l and dI_lm are pointers of type Eigen::Vector3f.

Any idea what should i improve to get better performance?

Comment: why don't you pull out the computation of y * wl and 2*y*wlm1 from the inner loop? (Though perhaps the compiler may optimize that)

Comment: That particular piece of code is too small/short to realistically benefit from parallelization due to thread management overhead (can't find a duplicate right now, but there are many). If you want actionable advice how to efficiently apply OpenMP you must post a larger portion of your code. Please still keep it as a [mcve].

Comment: Collapsing out a vectorizable inner loop is likely to be a bad move on most CPUs of the last 15 years, even if you set omp parallel for simd with a compiler which actually implements parallel simd.  DId you check whether adding collapse gives you satisfactory performance?  The normal reason for collapse is the case where your number of threads approaches or exceeds but doesn't exactly equal the number of outer loop trips, but you didn't give us a reason to believe that is your case.  Besides as already hinted you would need 1000 outer loops to make parallelization worth while.

Comment: If this is the first parallel region in your code you are (mostly) measuring the cost of thread creation. So execute an empty #pragma omp parallel before starting the timer. p.s. Intel Advisor https://software.intel.com/en-us/advisor makes it much easier to find good places to parallelize (you may qualify for a free copy, if not you get three months free [and then can renew :-)]). (Full disclosure: I work for Intel)